# intermittent 412 error when calling Google Directory API to patch a user's password

Tags: c#, rest, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

My application's main function is to change a Google G-Suite user's password using Google's Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1 nuget package.

The API call works 95% of the time (and resets a target user's password), but intermittently, the API call throws an exception with the Message text:

> Precondition Failed [412] Errors [ Message[Precondition Failed] Location[If-Match - header] Reason[conditionNotMet] Domain[global] ]

I've done lots of research and it seems that there is a client-specified pre-condition being included in a (REST?) call that the API is making toward the Google API server and the server is determining that the condition is not being met (see  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) or the state of the object being changed is bad (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors ). The strange thing is, everything does work nearly all of the time, but then fails every now and then. It really seems like it is some kind of a resource based error (too many calls submitted recently, too many users licensed in the domain) or maybe bad data (bad or missing password, bad user) or even permissions (user is in a group/OU that can'b be managed). But the error message gives nothing to go on and I've mostly  ruled out the most obvious of the possibilities. I've googled the exact message and found numerous people with similar complaints, but no documented causes.

Correction from original: I am able to capture REST calls with Fiddler (with https capture configured), but I can't reproduce the original error while capturing, so it doesn't help much.

Any suggestions for how to reproduce and/or troubleshoot the issue?

Here is the code (please ignore any obvious typos-I had to cut/paste/merge from a few sources to assemble a small simple example)--the real code definitely works nearly all of the time:

```
{
    userEmail = googleUser + "@" + domain; // e.g. BobSmith@myGoogleDomain.com
    
    // service is an instance of Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.DirectoryService
    var userget = service.Users.Get(userEmail); 
    User userob = userget.Execute();
    userob.ChangePasswordAtNextLogin = false;
    userob.Password = password;
    patchRequest=service.Users.Patch(userob, userEmail);
    patchRequest.Execute();
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

Comment: Using Fiddler, I can see there is an "etag" value in the outgoing REST call to reset the password. Its value appears to be set from the first user lookup being done. If I manually (in the debugger) corrupt the etag value being sent out with the password change call, it gives the reported error, so it seems like the etag value (or something similar) is being corrupted somehow.

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce your issue to study it better, but I haven't been able to. Could you please share with us a sample request and response pair that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce it (which is half the battle!). I can say that on Dec 27, 2019, my app made multiple call's to google's API and a small percentage of them returned the error, but the rest worked fine. Since then I have not been able to reproduce. It may well have been a time-based issue on google's side. As potential fixes I have upgraded my code to the latest version of the API (1.43.0) and have changed my code to call Update() instead of Patch() to update a user, per google's recommendations in their documentation. Monitoring to see if that helped...